# Firefox: 100% and inner padding?

Tags: html, css, firefox, padding

I have a div with a width of 100% and paragraphs inside. The div has padding of 1.1em. On Chrome evrything works as expected - div spans to 100% of parent's space and paragraphs get squeezed a little due to the padding.

However on Firefox div expends to 100% + padding. How to do I force inner padding on firefox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*How to do I force inner padding on firefox?*

Use [`box-sizing: border-box;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) for the element, as by default, the `padding` `border` and `margin` are counted outside the element.

Using `box-sizing: border-box;` will alter the box model, which will make the `padding` and `border` to be counted inside the element instead of outside.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/SPdc3/) *Without `box-sizing`*

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/SPdc3/1/) *With `box-sizing`*

See the difference? You won't get a horizontal scroll bar in the second demonstration, where am using `border-box` value for `box-sizing` property.

Comment: Hmm, I tried adding it while inspecting with firefox, but it didnt do anything. Worked once placed into the stylesheet.